# three js orbit controls moves mesh back to center

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera, controls, position

I have the following code that moves a mesh up along the y axis in the scene when a menu is shown.

```
if(mobile_size <= 600){
    mesh.position.y = 5; //make the check for mobile
    console.log(mesh.position);
}else{
    mesh.position.z = 0;
    console.log(mesh.position);
}
```

but when i use my orbit controls it is still centered on the mesh being at position (0,0,0) so the controls break / feel weird. 
So to fix this error i used the following method to update the orbitcontrols:

```
orbit.target = mesh.position;
orbit.update();
```

but when i do this my mesh moves back to the center of the screen... I dont want this. And i dont know why this is happening or how to fix it. I will add two images to show what is happening. 
[image: this is where the mesh should be (on ypos 5)]
[image: after calling orbit.update it moves everything to ypos 0]

So the first images shows the desired position of the mesh.
the second image shows that the position is reset to the center after calling `orbit.update()`

So how do i fix this?
All suggestions are very welcome.

if more code is required, or if something is not clear please let me know so i can clarify.

Comment: You shouldn't do `orbitControls.position = mesh.position` as orbitControls might then modify the position of the object. Instead do `orbitControls.position.copy(mesh.position)` when appropriate.

Comment: Why not to change the size of the renderer, when you show the menu?

Comment: @prisoner849 yeah didnt think of that :P nice suggestion!